# Why are some people just not getting knocked out?

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, punching

I just watched this compilation https://youtu.be/p4aRkLSgNGY. I've been sparring for a few months now, and even though I've never been knocked out, I can see how one would get knocked out. In this video though, the fighters are just eating the hits with their chins.

So my question is: Why, and how are they able to do that? Just take uppercuts that would send most people flying, and still be ok with it? I'm sure they're concussed like crazy after that, but how are they still up? Weak hits from their opponents? Drugs? Natural resiliency? Something that can be trained?

Comment: It's the strikes you don't see that knock you out, not the ones you see coming.

Comment: So if you're ready for it you can just "prepare" and take them? Like tense some muscles and resist them?

Comment: I don't know the exact mechanism (hence I wrote a comment not an answer!), but as I understand it, the preparation is what 'saves' you.

Comment: Ok makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boxers, kickboxers, and MMA fighters train to be able to minimize the damage caused by a hit to the head. It's actually pretty hard to knock anyone out who has trained for any length of time in these arts.

One thing to realize is that you have a natural instinct to flinch whenever you see something coming towards your face. You might still get hit, but the fact that you saw it ahead of time means you began to get your hands up and your head out of the way. This diminishes the impact.

Another thing to realize is that tucking the chin can mitigate a lot of the impact force. Instead of it shocking your brain, it gets reinforced by your body and prevents the sudden recoil of the head. Boxers, kickboxers, and MMA people are taught this on day one.

And then there's conditioning. Getting hit in sparring by guys that aren't necessarily trying to knock you out but are still hitting hard will toughen you up and get you ready to take hits. Your body will adapt to it.

Conditioning also means strength and stamina. Having a strong body that doesn't get fatigued during a fight is vital. If you gas half-way into the first round, your odds of getting knocked out go up a lot. It means your defense becomes weak. You stop being able to move to avoid hits. You'll go down quickly.

There's age and previous knock-out history as well. The more you've been KO'd, the more likely you'll be KO'd. I think it's just that the body wears as you get older and have been subjected to more damage.

Having a history of being KO’d before also means you’re less likely to continue fighting. The people left in the game are, therefore, people who either have little experience or who have lots of experience. Those who stay as fighters a long time are people who don’t get KO’d easily. So it’s kind of a selection bias. These aren’t typical people. These are exceptional people.

Lastly, there's genetics. That probably counts for a lot. How your body is put together, whether or not you're able to grow muscle in all the right places, your brain's response to low/high blood pressure and adrenaline, etc. Genetics plays a role. How big? I don't think anyone knows.

Hope that helps!

Comment: As a caveat, there's some evidence that the techniques that fighters use to avoid getting knocked out are a strong factor behind their more long-term damage, although it's confounded by the fact that someone who doesn't get knocked out with one blow is going to be getting hit by more of them.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the main factor. The more time spent getting hit, the more long-term damage you'll accumulate, particular brain damage. So it's a double-edged sword. Yes, you're skilled at fighting, but you're also hurting yourself more and more as time goes on. Someone who's not as good a fighter might quit competing altogether, thereby saving their brain from cumulative, long-term damage. Ironic.

Comment: Adding my two cents about conditioning - some boxing classes do have "resillency" training - when your partner is hitting your head, and you are standing still, "eating" it with your defence. With time, hitting becomes harder - it is somewhat like M-T leg conditioning with light strikes to the log.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of boxing, it's mostly "natural resiliency", combined with strong neck muscles from training. For the higher weight classes in boxing, it's a process of elimination: the boxers that get knocked out (repeatedly) don't advance and usually leave the sport, a form of "natural selection", that results in the top ranked boxers in the higher weight classes having a "natural resiliency" to getting knocked out.

One example from the past is Muhammad Ali, who was able to take punches that would KO most of the other heavyweights at the time. This doesn't mean there isn't brain damage, and most of the higher weight class boxers, especially ones with longer careers, ended up with fairly severe brain damage.

Answer (score 1):

I read why you get knocked out from a punch: its because of the twisting motion that disrupts a link in the brain. The twist is in your brain stem, that is why when you get hit in the corner of your jaw, your head twist along with the brain stem and the lights go out.

I couldn't find anything on why some seem immune to being knocked out and some have a glass jaw. It probably has something to do with seeing it coming: you turn your head in a certain way, making the twist not as much. I have never been knocked out either and I crashed a 3-wheeler, landed on my head and broke my jaw. Didn't even phase me. I'm sure I can, just hasn't found the spot.

I think there has to be something physical also. Some MMA guys don't lose very often and some can't make it thru the first round and the ones with good records defiantly eat their share of punches. I have seen some eat a sucker punch and all it did was piss him off and others take the lightest hit and the lights are out.

Comment: If you read about this somewhere, please provide a reference so others can read it too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to this question but thought I'd add my experiences with a seemingly natural "immunity" to getting knocked unconscious and/or getting a concussion (I know that no one is ACTUALLY immune to these) I am and have always been tall and thin (at 43 I'm 6'/ 165lbs, which is heavy for me) I don't have a super muscular frame so the thick neck doesn't help me, I'm not nor have I ever been a fighter. Took some different martial arts growing up but nothing too serious. I also was able to avoid most fist fights as a kid. I was however often hit in the head but have not once been knocked unconscious nor suffered a concussion. I've been hit in the head with baseball bats, skateboards, rocks, bottles, basketballs, baseballs, golf balls, logs and the list goes on. I've been hit in the head hard enough to have seen "stars" and/or hear "ringing" yet never have I been knocked out. I even had an incident happen in which am amateur MMA fighter whom was substantially bigger, stronger than I (roughly 6'3" or 6'4" and a very muscular 240 to 260 lbs) hit me so hard with one punch it ended up breaking my nose, my ocular bone, chipping three of my front teeth AND splitting the back of my head open (splitting my head because I was backed up to a stucco cement wall) I dropped to one knee but immediately was able to stand right back up...no blacking out, no memory gaps or anything. I was pissed off but completely clear minded otherwise. I was also slightly intoxicated, by maybe two or three beers. EMT's had been called and they looked me over and other than the obvious damage (left eye was completely swelled shut and blackened, laceration under the eye as well, also swollen and lacerated nose, and head plus bleeding orally because of the chipped teeth and all) said I didn't appear to have a concussion. They of course highly recommended I go to the ER but not having medical insurance at the time and having a job I had to be to just a few hours later prevented me from going. I didn't actually know anything other than my teeth had been broken until the next day at 5a.m. I showed up to my job(forklift operator loading and unloading trucks at the time) just to have my boss force me to go see a doctor.... apparently it's "unsafe" to operate a vehicle of any kind with only one eye functioning fully lol! (I knew it wasn't but I needed the money cuz I had a wife and four kids to take care of so I was gonna try to work regardless) Anyway, the doctor did his thing to find out about all the broken stuff and what not but still no signs of concussion, brain bleeding, swelling or any of that. I've fallen from some pretty high heights landing on both my feet and not on my feet and have been in an auto accident in which I hit a brick wall at about 45-50 mph sitting in the front seat, passenger side (no airbag deployment on my side) and the wall just had earth behind it meaning was didn't go through we just abruptly came to a stop.... No whiplash or anything then either.
I don't have any explanation for any of this and don't know if it helps anyone in any way in coming to some sort of determination as to why this can happen but this seemed as good a place as any for me to share this info.....oh yeah, this is prolly completely unrelated but I am also completely immune to "brain freeze"(I've never experienced it) and "hangover" symptoms.  I've only rarely ever had any kind of headache and on those very few rare occasions I did experience a headache it only lasted a few seconds up to a minute, maybe. I apologize for the length of my response btw.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your response! I'd invite you to take [the tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [the help section](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about our format. We tend to be more fact based, rather than discussion/anecdotal. As such, you answer may get downvoted. Welcome, and we look forward to hearing more from you!

Answer (score -1):

I think this really really relies on your neck. My dad has been hit with baseball bats, crowbars, over thousands of times punched right in the head and has never not once been knocked out. He has the biggest neck you would ever see. Also genes might also play a role in it to. Like how most explain, that liquid that keeps your brain from getting knocked out every time you move, might just be significantly more than the average person. But if you're like me and have half the family being tough fighters, remember that the other half could be dominant in your body so your neck and "brain protect liquid" might not be as good as you’d think.